Why do dividend yields converge to zero?
According to the dividend discount model, a stock price is the discounted value of its dividends, where one assumes the dividends grow annually by some rate $g$ and are discounted at $r$, the required return on the stock, where $g < r$.
However this implies that if the stock delivers its required return, the dividend yield (the ratio of dividend to price) converges to zero.
That makes no sense tho?

Maybe you can add more details on how you came to that conclusion?

No, that is not true.
The dividend discount model is a model (a fairly crude model) for the price of a stock. It suggests that a dividend grows at a constant rate for perpetuity and that that cashflow is discounted by some constant rate of interest for perpetuity.
$$
P = \sum_{i=1}^\infty D_0 \frac{(1+g)^i}{(1+r)^i}
$$
Using the regular trick for the geometric sum of a series, this is equivalent to,
$$
P = D_0 \frac{1+g}{r-g} = \frac{D_1}{r-g}
$$
It is quite clear that if $g>r$ this sum does not converge and hence the model is useless.
At any future point one could say that the value of the price under this model was,
$$
P_t = \frac{D_t}{r-g}
$$
and the dividend yield (dividend divided by price) is an assumed constant under this model,
$$ 
\frac{D_t}{P_t} = (r-g)
$$
